# Python formatting Error (unsupported)

Tags: python, formatting

I am building a string with this method.
But for some reason I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 38
```

I have no idea where this is coming from. I checked for typos but nothing.

```
s = "SELECT %s FROM %s "
data = [colName, tableName]

if whereRoughly:
    s+= "(WHERE "
        for i in range(len(whereRoughly[0])):
            s += "%s LIKE '%%s%' "
            if i+1 < len(whereRoughly[0]): s += "OR "
            data.append(whereRoughly[0][i])
            data.append(whereRoughly[1])
     s+= ")"

s += "ORDER BY %s;"
data.append("desc")

print s
print data
print s % tuple(data)
```

Here I call all the upper code

```
s.makeSelect(tableName="students", whereRoughly=([1,2], "Wes"))
```

This is the actual output

```
SELECT %s FROM %s (WHERE %s LIKE '%%s%' OR %s LIKE '%%s%' )ORDER BY %s;
['*', 'students', 1, 'Wes', 2, 'Wes', 'desc']
```

Comment: Also, you really, really shouldn't use ``+=`` on strings in python. You should properly use combinations of ``format`` and ``join``.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
"'%%s%'"
```

There's no format code `%'`, and trying to use it causes an error.

```
>>> "'%%s%'" % "foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 5
```

I assume that you're trying to get the SQL `LIKE` syntax like `'%foo%'` (enclosed on either side by `%` and a single quote.

To get that formatting using the old-style `%` formatting in Python, you need to escape the leading and trailing percents like this:

```
>>> "'%%%s%%'" % "foo"
"'%foo%'"
```

(See the [docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting))

This is cleaner with modern-style [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> "'%{0}%'".format('foo')
"'%foo%'"
```

(also, the comment above about not using `+=` to build strings is a valid one -- prefer `format` and `join`).